# How do I avoid cast operator() and access operator[] conflict?

Tags: c++, casting, operator-overloading, typecasting-operator

I was certain it was asked before, but I couldn't find it.

I have a class encapsulating `std::string`. Inside I want to overloaded both typecasts to `char*` and the access `operator[]`.

```
class String
{
public :
    String(const char* s) { m_str = s; }
    const char* str() const  { return m_str.c_str(); }
    char* str()  {  return &m_str[0]; }
    char operator[](size_t pos) const { return m_str[pos]; }
    char& operator[](size_t pos) { return m_str[pos]; }
    operator const char*() const { return str(); }  // cast operator
    operator char*() { return str(); }  // cast operator
protected:
    std::string m_str;
};

void main()
{
    String s = "1234";
    if(s[0] != '1')   //'String::operator []': 4 overloads have similar conversions !!!!!
        std::cout << "Error" << endl;
}
```

Problem is now of course when I try to use `String []` I receive error:

> *4 overloads have similar conversions*

The compiler can't decide what to do:

1. use the overload `operator[]` directly
2. first convert to `char*`, use `operator()`, and finally `operator[]` over the resulting `char*` array

Is there some way to keep both operators? For many functions, it is very helpful to have `char*` and `const char*` to use **operator()** of `String` but in all other cases directly the **operator[]** (not trying to convert to `char*` first).

I suppose the answer to this is probably *No*. That is why in **`std::string`** there is no **`char*`** cast operator, but maybe something has changed in more recent C++ standards?

**EDIT:** I can compile the above with GCC but it fails with VS (x86).

> *Error C2666 'String::operator []': 4 overloads have similar conversions*

Comment: "...but it fails" -- care to show the errors? Also, turn on warnings. Further, lots of your code isn't necessary and only distracts, you need to extract and provide a [mcve] for your question. Include that inline, not with a bunch of "EDIT:..." sections. Oh, BTW, the title line is not for things that tags are better used for, remove the C++ there.

Comment: I have given the error in the code section - "String::operator []': 4 overloads have similar conversions"

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica The question should be re-opened, the error is reproducible in 32-bit mode with `clang-9` and `mscv`, see https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/T4yTGH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always compile your code with warnings enabled, for `gcc` and `clang` the command line option is `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`. The warnings will tell you that `operator[]` needs to return a value.

---

In expression `s[0]` in 32-bit mode `clang` and `msvc` compilers consider the *standard conversion* of `int` index to `unsigned` (32-bit `size_t`) to be of the same rank as *user-defined conversion* of `String` to `char*`. See the compiler error messages [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/T4yTGH). The latter conversions being a *user-defined conversion* has worse rank than any *standard conversion*, but the compilers cannot resolve this tie. I am not sure which exactly standard rule applies here.

A fix is to add another overload of `operator[]` that accepts a signed `ptrdiff_t` index:

```
char operator[](ptrdiff_t pos) const { return m_str[pos]; }
char& operator[](ptrdiff_t pos) { return m_str[pos]; }
```

Comment: Please try it with x86, for me it builds in VS2017 x64 only.

Comment: It is a more interesting issue, i will remove my answer for now.

Comment: Thanks, Maxim. Now I see that solution is to use int's in operator [] - can you explain a little more why it work with int's but not with size_t? I understand now that conflict happens only when promotion to unsigned int (size_t) must be done, and only for x86.